# Difference between dataType jsonp and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I download Jquery UI autoload, looking to remote-jsonp.html. This is ajax function but i open console.. I can't see any request in my console...

What is difference between dataType;"jsonp" and dataType;"JSON"

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                            value: item.name
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
```

**Reference** http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote-jsonp.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`dataType: jsonp` for cross-domain request, that means request to different domain and `dataType: json` for same domain-same origin request.

> Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the
>   end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending
>   a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache
>   option is set to true.

Read about **[same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)**

Read more about **[jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

Comment: `cross-browser` or `cross-domain`? :s

Comment: @Joy Definitely cross-domain.

Answer (score 8):

With JSONP you shouldn't see an ajax request if that's what you're looking for. You should however see a request for the resource because JSONP is used for cross domain calls to pull in data from different domains.

It returns your JSON data wrapped in a function name. jQuery handles the function name behind the scenes and passes the data into your success handler. The data is loaded by dynamically creating a script element with the src attribute pointing to the service being called and then attached to the browser's DOM. Then the browser makes a request to the resource and the web service responds with the callback function and data.