# Having trouble with this ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Every time I call the `whatever` function below, the `error` function fires.

Using Firebug I was able to determine that the ajax call is appending the json string in `data` to the end of the `url` querystring.  Like so:

> https://example.com/api/Controller/Method?callback=jQuery203016199810379339108_1481539294422&{"json":"data"}&_=1481539294423

I intended it to be sent in the request body.  So... how do I get `data` to be sent via the request body instead of the url querystring?

```
function whatever(model, url) {
        $.support.cors = true;

        var data = JSON.stringify(model);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: {'x-whatever': 'whatever'},
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: data,
            success: function (msg) { },
            error: function (request, status, error) { 
                console.log(url);
                console.log(status + error); 
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: What's the URL you're calling? Is it cross domain? Does the recipient support JSONP? It's not directly interchangeable with JSON. Also, check the console to discover the exact response code from the request, and hopefully a description of the issue

Comment: Are you sure, `https://example.com/api/Controller/Method?callback=jQuery203016199810379339108_1481539294422&{"json":"data"}&_=1481539294423` is valid and correctly represented by the browswr?

Comment: check `datatype:"jsonp"` .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852652/difference-between-datatype-jsonp-and-json

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like a valid request to me. There's no `=` between the two `&`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: That's how Firebug reports it.  It doesn't look valid to me either.

Comment: @SamAxe How are you even generating it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan:  This is cross-domain:  Local (dev box) MVC4 web site calling Azure-hosted WebApi2 endpoint.

Comment: well, its a JSONP ```dataType: "jsonp"``` request which prepend jQueryAutoGeneratedToken for security. Make it ```dataType: "json"```.

Comment: @SamAxe ok, in which case this will only work if the recipient domain includes CORS headers in the response. If you can let me know the error you see in the console I can guide you further

Comment: @PraveenKumar: I pass `http://example.com/api/Controller/Method` in as the `url` parameter.  jQuery does the rest.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: the console log displays `errorerror`.  the ajax error function `status` parameter = "error", as does the `error` parameter.

Comment: Check the network tab and find the request in there

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: there's nothing in the response for that request.  It's not a valid request for the server.  Server returns a 500 error.

Comment: @kishor10d: setting `dataType` to "json" makes the ajax call not happen at all.

Comment: @SamAxe: Can you do something with CORS as @RoryMcCrossan suggested. But if you allowed CORS to ```*``` then it will allow all the request (no security :-( );

Comment: I dont care about security right now.  I have cors enabled on the controller method:  `<Cors.EnableCors("*", "*", "*")>`.  I'm pretty sure the error is in what jQuery ajax is doing to mangle that url.

Comment: You don't have to use `*`, you can restrict CORS to a single domain if needed. @SamAxe try removing JSONP. I presume you're just returning JSON from the API. Also try removing `contentType` as well, just to test

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: setting dataType to "json" makes the ajax call not happen at all.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you. There's just not enough information here. Without seeing the errors generated from the requests there could literally be any number of errors happening.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: also, while `dataType` = `jsonp`, the odd url that is used is a GET request, not a POST.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Yeah, I get it.  I wish I had more data to share.  Thanks for giving it a shot.

Comment: That last error is because JSONP can only be transferred over a GET request

Comment: Also, you need a callback parameter to handle the jsonp (ajax-jsonp syntax).