# Get certain data from json (google geocode api)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, geocode

I try to get a certain data from my json request from the google geocode api.

My code looks like this:

```
$('#test').on('focusout', function() {
    var address = $('#ustreet').val() + " " + $('#ustreetnr').val() + ", " + $('#uplz').val(); 
    $('#uaddress').val(address);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json.geometry.location.lat);
            console.log(json);
        }
    });
});
```

My results from request are fine and looking like this:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Celler%20Weg%2055,%2021079

But I got problems to get just the "lat & lng" values from geometry->location and store it into a var.

> ReferenceError: json is not defined

I am for sure a JavaScript/jQuery beginner but for an other project with another API it worked great the same way I tried it here ...

I hope I can get some help here :)

Greetings from poland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `dataType: 'jsonp'` to `dataType: 'json'`.

> JSONP stands for JSON with Padding.

`dataType: jsonp` is for cross-domain requests, that means request to different domains. `dataType: json` for the same domain-same origin request.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Prunesstraat 4 opheusden',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok this works. I used jsonp cause i read this here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852652/difference-between-datatype-jsonp-and-json) and thought I need to use jsonp for "cross-domain" reasons. And how exactly can I console.log a certain data like mentioned in the question? :)

Comment: Yeah, but you are not doing a cross-domain request.

Comment: Can you quick post how I access/get just a certain data from json request? Would be realy nice :)

Comment: Yeah sure, which property would you like to retrieve?

Comment: I want to retrive the "lat and lng" values from results => 0 => geometry => location

Comment: Figured it out: console.log(json.results[0].geometry.location.lat);

Comment: Yep, thats indeed the correct way to retrieve the desired values.